# Pure CSS Vintage sign, is it possible?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make this sign in pure CSS, the arrow and the car looks like it might stop any attempts with making it

Thanks

[Sign I want to make -->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh7xG.jpg)

Comment: It is totally possible to do this.  I'm amazed at the things people can create with pure css.
[Check out this pug burger made with CSS](https://codepen.io/kateanhalt/pen/bWmJGV?utm_source=CSS-Weekly&utm_campaign=Issue-266&utm_medium=web)

Comment: Why do it with CSS?...SVG would be the obvious choice here.